# AngularJS directive conflicts in different environment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi guys so i'm having a problem with a directive

Error in console :

> Error: [$compile:multidir]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$compile/multidir?p0=attendeesGroup&p1=&p…3A%3AeventCode%22%20attendees%3D%22attendees%22%20search%3D%22search%22%3E
>       at app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1
>       at bt (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)
>       at ai (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)
>       at app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1
>       at app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1
>       at p.$eval (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)
>       at p.$digest (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)
>       at p.$apply (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)
>       at ft (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)
>       at tt (app?v=i8y6GpTaEb1RAE-DuP0yglQXfZKxm4UD1Y48hiIfGJg1:1)

Error from angular site

```
Multiple directives [attendeesGroup, attendeesGroup] asking for template on: <attendees-group event="::eventCode" attendees="attendees" search="search">
```

Full description [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=attendeesGroup&p1=&p2=attendeesGroup&p3=&p4=template&p5=%3Cattendees-group%20event%3D%22::eventCode%22%20attendees%3D%22attendees%22%20search%3D%22search%22%3E)
the thing is that it works ok on my localhost , it works ok on a 2nd (test) environments but it does not work on the 3rd (pre-prod)

This is the HTML

```
    <div ng-hide="groups">
        <attendees-group event="::eventCode" attendees="attendees" search="search" />
    </div>

    <div ng-show="groups">
        <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
            <div ng-show="$parent.attendeesNumber[$index] = (group.Attendees | filter:search).length">
                <h6 class="med-heading">
                    <span ng-bind="::group.Value || 'Other'"></span>
                    <span style="font-size: 75%; margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer;"
                          ng-if="canManage && group.Value"
                          class="fa fa-paint-brush"
                          ng-click="::changeColor(group.Value)"></span>
                </h6>
                <attendees-group event="::eventCode" attendees="group.Attendees" search="search" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="checkAttendeesNumber()">
            <h6 class="med-heading">
                <small>No attendees found. </small>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the directive

```
angular.module('Events').directive('attendeesGroup', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { event: '=', attendees: '=', search: '=' },
            templateUrl: '/Content/AngularApp/Attendees/Components/AttendeesGroup/Template.html',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) { }
        };
    }
]);
```

Any ideas, suggestions ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are declaring the attendeesGroup multiple times in your angular code.

Comment: nop, it is the only "attendeesGroup" across all .js files and it is used only as a directive like posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i've discovered the issue, this answer may or may not be of help depending on how the server and deployment process was configured, but gives a suggestion and possible cause of problem.

So we are using jenkins for deployment on integration environment and Octopus for moving the packages from integration to the next and so one. The issue was that for some reason (maybe this is how octopus works or maybe it was configured this way, don't know) when deployment was made from integration to the next environment, test in my case, the files from previous deployment where kept and when the bundled was done it included both previous version as well as the new one (*.js), that resulted in a bundled having duplicated directive. I've solved the problem by deleting the previous version files from test environment.